# Immersion $\mathbb{S}^n\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Immersion $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$

As $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ it's not compact, i can give immersion given by $$(x,y,z,t)\to e^t(x, y, z).$$

or i'm wrong. Could you give me some other immersion.

Comment: Your mapping is actually an embedding (and generalizes in "an obvious way" to $S^{n} \times \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}^{n+1}$). Or is that not your question...?

Comment: How to use this to see that $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^1$ is embedding in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; what exactly is your final goal? (And if necessary, could you please edit your question and title to match?) :)

Comment: I want to prove that if $M^n$ is a product of spheres so i can embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: @Jimbo: Your final question is a much more interesting question, so you should change your question. You have to understand normal bundles and Whitney sums of bundles.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, but I can't help adding some more explicit hints to @Ted Shifrin comment.

1) Any manifold $M\subset\mathbb R^m$ has an open tubular nbhd diffeomorphic to the normal bundle $\nu M$ of $M$ in $\mathbb R^m$.

2) If a manifold is defined in some open ngbd $U\subset \mathbb R^m$ by a submersion $U\to\mathbb R^k$ its normal bundle is trivial: the gradients $\nabla f_i$ give a diffeo $M\times\mathbb R^k\equiv\mathbb\nu M\equiv U$.

For a sphere $M=\mathbb S^{p}$ this is the content of the initial question with $U=\mathbb R^{p+1}\setminus\{0\}$.

3) If $M$ is defined by a submersion as in 2), then the product $M\times N$ with any manifold $N\subset\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^k\times\mathbb R^{n-k}$, $n\ge k$, can be embedded in $\mathbb R^{m+n-k}$.

4) Argue by induction with $Y=\mathbb S^{p_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb S^{p_r}$ and $X=\mathbb S^{p}$.

This is a quite simple argument for the beautiful fact that *any product of spheres is a hypersurface*.