# Embed $S^{p} \times S^q$ in $S^d$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, surgery-theory

Can we embed $S^{p} \times S^q$ in $S^d$ with all the nice properties, what are the allowed values of $p$ and $q$ for $d=2,3,4$ where $p+q \leq d$?

=For $d=2$=

I suppose that we cannot embed $S^{1} \times S^1$ in $S^2$.

=For $d=3$=

Can we embed $S^{2} \times S^1$ in $S^3$?

=For $d=4$=

Can we embed $S^{1} \times S^3$ in $S^4$?

Can we embed $S^{2} \times S^2$ in $S^4$?

Can we embed $S^{1} \times S^2$ in $S^4$? Yes?

Can we embed $S^{1} \times S^1 \times S^1$ in $S^4$? Yes?

What are the proofs and explanations?

Comment: Surely you'll need $p+q\lt d$; embedding in $S^d$ is the same as embedding in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and closed manifolds of dimension $d$ can only embed in dimensions $\geq d+1$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki That should be an answer

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Unfortunately, I don't know much more about the problem than that relatively-trivial correction. (Though I think a coordinate-based approach is actually reasonably clean here for the case with just two factors, and if I can make the argument clear then I'll post it)

Comment: You can embed $S^p \times S^q$ in $S^d$ if and only if $p + q < d$. The 'only if' part is what @StevenStadnicki said in the comment above, and the 'if' part is obvious as one can always embed $S^p \times S^q$ in $\Bbb R^d$ [consider the cell complex structure given by $e^0 \sqcup e^p \sqcup e^q \sqcup e^{p+q}$] for $p + q \leq d$ and compose it with the one-point compactification map $\Bbb R^d \to S^d$.

Comment: You can embed any product of spheres in the real space of dimension one above its dimension. You can probably prove this yourself, but if you need a hint, search the above (more general) problem; it has been resolved on this site before.

Comment: Here there is such a solution:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135819/immersion-mathbbsn-times-mathbbr-to-mathbbrn1/1145653#1145653. For spheres this is really elementary, because tubes for them are trivial: $\mathbb S^p\times\mathbb R\hookrightarrow\mathbb R^{p+1}$ via $(x,t)\mapsto e^tx$ (the image is $\mathbb R^{p+1}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks Jesus RS, how about [this unlinking the sphere problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245689/surgery-to-unlink-s1-and-s2-in-s4)??