# Linking of $S^p$ and $S^q$ in the $\mathbb{R}^d$ space

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

Can we have a nontrivial linking of a $S^p$ sphere and a $S^q$ sphere in the $\mathbb{R}^d$ space (or in the ${S}^d$ space)? I suppose that [it can happen only if $p+q<d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240628/embed-sp-times-sq-in-sd).

For example, we can have:

(1) $S^1$ and $S^1$ can be linked in $\mathbb{R}^3$ $\to$ True.

My question is that can we have:

(2) $S^2$ and $S^1$ can be linked in $\mathbb{R}^4$? $\to$ True?

(3) $S^1$ and $S^1$ can be linked in $\mathbb{R}^5$? $\to$ False?

(4) $S^1$ and $S^2$ can be linked in $\mathbb{R}^5$? $\to$ False?

(5) $S^1$ and $S^3$ can be linked in $\mathbb{R}^5$? $\to$ True?

(6) $S^2$ and $S^2$ can be linked in $\mathbb{R}^5$? $\to$ True?

And the answers are the same if we replace the $\mathbb{R}^d$ space by the ${S}^d$ space, correct?

Comment: Out of the blue I'd say: iff $d=p+q+1$

Comment: See the first chapter of Rolfsen's book, knots and links. If $n \geq 2$ and $c \geq n/2+2$, there is a bijection between (piecewise linear) links $S_n \cup S_n \hookrightarrow S^{n+c}$ and elements of $\pi_n(S^{c-1})$. In particular there are 15 ways to link two copies of $S^{10}$ in $S^{13}$. If your dimensions are small enough ($\text{max}(p,q) + 1 < d/2$) you can use a Whitney argument to see that every embedding $S^p \cup S^q \to \Bbb R^d$ is the same (i.e., isotopic). I think you can improve that less than sign to a $\leq$ but am not willing to promise it.